# Unable to update the dependencies of the project. The dependencies for the object cannot be determined

Tags: windows-installer, vsinstaller

Installer project contains references of multiple DLLs. Out of which One DLL is referenced from GAC from which I am getting "Unable to update the dependencies of the project. The dependencies for the object cannot be determined." error on compiling the installer project. I am using VS 2017.

I have already tried removing the installer project and adding it again.

Also tried editing the vdproj file to remove ScatterAssemblies section for any corrupted assembly.

Tried Closing the solution and opening it again.

Expected Result: Installer project should build successfully and MSI should be generated.

Actual Result: Installer project is not compiling at all and giving me the above error to unable the dependencies.

Comment: Same issue in VS 2019. The DLL is ACS.SPiiPlusNET.dll ... which is for communication with hardware. It refuses to build because this dll causes the "Unable to update the dependencies of the project" message. Strangely, this is in the "Output" and not error log. Also it's prefixed with "WARNING" so you would think it should not be fatal. If I remove that DLL then everything is fine.